# Dash AGGrid to add remove columns using a transposed pandas dataframe

Tags: ag-grid, plotly-dash, ag-grid-react

I am trying to use AGGrid to create a view where I first start with an empty dataframe having columns

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
df.columns = ["col1", "col2","col3","col4"]
df = df.T
```

In the aggrid I display the transposed empty dataframe as follows:

```
cols = [i for i in df.columns]
df["Metrics"]=df.index
df = df[["Metrics"]+cols]

columnDefs = [ { "headerName": col,'field': col, 'filter': True} for col in df.columns]

ag_grid = dag.AgGrid(
  id="table",
  rowData=df.to_dict("records"),
  columnDefs=columnDefs,
  style={'height': '800px'}
)
```

I want to be able to add/ remove a column from df. Is there a way to add a button to add/remove columns from the ag grid? I was exploring cell renderer but I could not find a way to do what I am looking to do.

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-ag-grid/change-cell-renderers